# can't find java applet html converter

Tags: java, html, applet

i've seen in numerous places (e.g. the sun/oracle site, reference books) mention of an html converter in the jdk's bin folder that's supposed to generate html that's friendly to a variety of browsers. yet i can't seem to find it, and i've checked on multiple machines with different versions of the jdk.

does anyone know where i can find it?
has it been deprecated for some reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ..supposed to generate html that's friendly to a variety of browsers.

What HTMLConverter generated was not HTML.  It was not valid according to *any* W3C HTML specification.  Good riddance to it.

Today the best option is to use the `deployJava.js` as linked from the [applet info. page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/applet/info).  It is the script that Sun was recommending before the Oracle buy-out, & Oracle has stuck by it.